# Archlinux SFTP indicated package length

Tags: ssh, sftp, arch-linux

I use Archlinux as a pure server system. The user "http" is authorized for ssh access. In this way I access the /var/www directory for the stored websites.

Recently, the login and the folder access are extremely slow. In addition, I cannot partially copy files. I log in to Cyberduck and want to upload a folder with files. It then creates a few files and shows the error "indicated Package length too large". I tried the whole thing with scp on the server. There scp still sticks 5 files.

I am grateful for all possible solutions ...